# I have problems with command that gets what user typed after command

Tags: discord.py

I am doing a Discord Bot for one SandBox page. 
I have already made a program that scraps the data from ANY user you want it to. (It's input and after that it scraps the data)
Now there is a new problem. I want to make a command "rr2.info.UserHere"
The rr2. is prefix, but I want to make a command that gets what you typed after rr2.info. and saves it into a variable.

I have tried with some code I found online, but it wasn't working. After that I couldn't find ANYTHING else.

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message():
    if message.content.startswith('rr2.info.'):
        #This is the part I need help with! :D
```

I need a way of getting ANYTHING typed after rr2.info. and that command done!

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good practice to use the `on_message()` as commands.

Better use [`command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html) fom [`discord.ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html).

Apparently you're looking for a way to store the user input into a variable, here is how you can do :

#### Using a command

You have defined `rr2` as your `prefix`. Let's assume you are using a **cog** system :

```py
@commands.command()
async def info(self, ctx, *, input: str):
   await ctx.send(input)
   return
```

The `await ctx.send(input)` line will send a message into the channel where the command has been used that contains what the user had passed as `input`.

So we have :

```
>>> rr2 info This is my input.
```

**Output :**

```py
'This is my input.'
```

#### Using on_message event

If you absolutely want to use an event to store the user input you can use :

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('rr2.info.'):
        input = message.content  # this will send the message with the 'rr2.info.' prefix

        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send(input)
```

This will have the exact same behaviour as the `command()` solution.

Comment: I tried both of them, command one doesn't work but the event one, it sends everything I said 10 times or something. How do I get it to send only things AFTER rr2.info. and sending it only once?

Comment: Also, when I do the command one I get error "Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "info.KOMKO190" is not found". I typed "rr2.info.KOMKO190"

Comment: For the command if you don't use cogs it won't work. You can use the decorator `@client.command()` instead. Also for the `event` think of using `process_command` method to allow you using the other commands. Try to add this `if` statment to avoid the bot to repeat indefinitely : `if message.author != client.user.id:`

Comment: I tried using @client.command() and it gets the same error. Also, where should I add it? Under the first if?

Comment: Unfortunately both of your codes are wrong. First code is not the format the OP wants, also why `return`? Second code is much worse, bot will just send the exact same message the member sent and since there is not check for if the message is from bot, the bot will reply to iteslf in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('rr2.info.'):
        # Split method returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator
        # Example input is 'rr2.info.uwu' then after calling input.split('rr2.info.')
        # we will get a list of ['', 'uwu'] , that's why we need to call second index to get the string after
        # 'rr2.info.' with [1]
        suffix = message.content.split('rr2.info.')[1]
        # Don't send it if it's empty, it will be empty if the user for example sent just 'rr2.info.'
        if suffix:
            await message.channel.send(suffix)
    else:
        # Overriding the default provided on_message forbids any extra commands from running.
        # To fix this, we add client.process_commands(message) line at the end of our on_message
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

I also suggest changing the name `client` to `bot` it's nicer.

If you would like to do this same thing with `commands` you would have to change the source code of commands ext functions, mainly because the `space` is used as separator between commands/arguments and you want to pass that as a single string.